# Shortcut to assign a negative value to primitives

Tags: java, variable-assignment, primitive

I remember reading somewhere in Java, possibly Oracle documentation that there is a shortcut to assign a flip value of a primitive.

Similar to:

```
int i = 0;
i += 3;
System.out.println(i);
```

Output is 3, but what if I wanted -3?
Or if given -3, make it positive 3?
Rather than doing

```
i = -i;
```

Isn't there a shortcut to do it in just the assignment operator?

Comment: `i *= -1;` is a valid one too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reverse the sign of a number you can do one of the following things:

```
i *= -1;
i = -i;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of options:

```
i = -3;
i += -3;
i -= 3;
```

Or even

```
i = 3;
System.out.println("-" + i);
```

Comment: `<insert deity here>` murders a kitten every time someone writes code like the last one.

Comment: @bcrist I have to say, the code is terrible, but also oddly amusing.

Comment: Oh, if we're putting up bad options, how about `i = (~i)+1`? :D

Answer (score 0):

`int i = -3;` is your easiest solution